# What format is this barcode reader data encoded in?

Tags: barcode-scanner, pyusb

I've got a CINO barcode reader that I'm using for this project. I've successfully connected it to my Linux machine and read its data using PyUSB. The looping data read from the device is such:

```
array('B', [0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
array('B', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
array('B', [0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
array('B', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
array('B', [0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
array('B', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
array('B', [0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
array('B', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

When I matched the data read from the barcode reader and the value of the barcode itself, I got this lookup table:

```
Character      Barcode value
A                  4
B                  5
c                  6
D                  7
E                  8
F                  9
G                 10
H                 11
I                 12
J                 13
K                 14
L                 15
M                 16
N                 17
O                 18
P                 19
Q                 20
R                 21
S                 22
T                 23
U                 24
V                 25
W                 26
X                 27
Y                 28
Z                 29
1                 30
2                 31
3                 32
4                 33
5                 34
6                 35
7                 36
8                 37
9                 38
0                 39
newline           40
```

Does anyone know what is this method of encoding?

Comment: What barcode type are you scanning?

Comment: @ssasa it's normal barcode, of the black and white ones...

Comment: what do you mean by "normal barcode"? Here there are at least 20 "normal" barcodes: http://www.barcodefaq.com/BarcodeMatch/

Comment: @ssasa Oh, I meant the usual design with vertical bars..anyway, based on the website, it's Code 39..

Comment: If it's Code 39, then you can check if your encoding matches the one on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39#Full_ASCII_Code_39

Comment: @ssasa No, it doesn';t match the code 39 encoding. I've double checked the barcode type and it's definitely code 39 (according to barcodefaq.com)

Comment: Could you please post the image here?